# Bash: creating a pipeline to list top 100 words

Tags: bash, sorting, pipe

Ok, so I need to create a command that lists the 100 most frequent words in any given file, in a block of text. 
What I have at the moment:

```
$ alias words='tr " " "\012" <hamlet.txt | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -r | head -n 10'
```

outputs

```
$ words
     14 the
     14 of
      8 to
      7 and
      5 To
      5 The
      5 And
      5 a
      4 we
      4 that
```

I need it to output in the following format:

```
the of to and To The And a we that
```

((On that note, how would I tell it to print the output in all caps?))

And I need to change it so that I can pipe 'words' to any file, so instead of having the file specified within the pipe, the initial input would name the file & the pipe would do the rest.

Comment: Please post a new follow-up question rather than editing a question which was already answered to your satisfaction. And please reward paxdiablo by marking his (?) answer as accepted.

Comment: Concur (on the new question point, not _necessarily_ the acceptance one). Changing the basic nature of the question breaks the whole Q&A concept, rendering answers to date useless. You should either post _all_ relevant details at the start or simply ask another question, linking back to this one for background info if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, taking your points one by one, though not necessarily in order.

---

You can change `words` to use standard input just by removing the `<hamlet.txt` bit since `tr` will take its input from standard input by default. Then, if you want to process a specific file, use:

```
cat hamlet.txt | words
```

or:

```
words <hamlet.txt
```

---

You can remove the effects of capital letters by making the first part of the pipeline:

```
tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'
```

which will lower-case your input before doing anything else.

---

Lastly, if you take that entire pipeline (with the suggested modifications above) and then pass it through a few more commands:

```
| awk '{printf "%s ", $2}END{print ""}'
```

This prints the second argument of each line (the word) followed by a space, then prints an empty string with terminating newline at the end.

---

For example, the following script `words.sh` will give you what you need:

```
tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | tr ' ' '\012' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -r
    | head -n 3 | awk '{printf "%s ", $2}END{print ""}'
```

(on one line: I've split it for readability) as per the following transcript:

```
pax> echo One Two two Three three three Four four four four | ./words.sh
four three two
```

You can achieve the same end with the following alias:

```
alias words="tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | tr ' ' '\012' | sort -n | uniq -c | sort -r
    | head -n 3 | awk '{printf \"%s \", \$2}END{print \"\"}'"
```

(again, one line) but, when things get this complex, I prefer a script, if only to avoid interminable escape characters :-)

Comment: Thank you! Still getting to grips with egrep - step by step (with a little guidance) is the best way for me!

Comment: The standard gripe about Useless Use of Cat goes here. I would advise against an alias, partly also because you want your command to handle named files, not just standard input. http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: Added the non-cat version but it's really a non-issue, especially since that was one way to _use_ the script/alias and _not_ part of the actual solution. If you're so short on processes that you can't start another one, you should probably write a single executable to do the lot :-)

Comment: @tripleee - in this case, I need to use an alias to satisfy my supervisor :( but it's useful info for the future

Comment: To formally comply with that requirement, you can create a script in $HOME/bin and then just set up an alias to the script.  For a number of reasons, a function would be preferrable to an alias, if you cannot use a script file.